# async/await function returns data only in console log but not in a variable

Tags: javascript, json, asynchronous, promise, async-await

A have a code for a simple api request, that should yield some data and it does! But it returns this data only in .then() block. Any attempt to save it in a variable lends in undefined. Where did I go wrong?

```
const link = "https://semalt.net/dev/api/v1/example/test/";
let queryData;
async function getData(link) {
  try {
    const result = await fetch(link);
    const data = await result.json();
    return data.result;
  } catch {
    alert(error);
  }
}
getData(link).then((array) => {
  queryData = array;
  console.log(queryData);
});
```

Comment: It stays `undefined` until the `then` callback actually runs. Don't access it before that happened.

Comment: This is how async function is supposed to work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron has really good examples regarding 'asynchronous flow'.

Comment: But I try to access it after! For example: getData(link).then((array) => {
  queryData = array;
  console.log(queryData);
}); console.log(queryData) // STILL UNDEFINED!

Comment: Like when I try to get the value after then() i still get undefined! Help me))

Comment: @Not-a-Whale I said *after* the (asynchronous!) callback *runs*. Not *below* the `then()` call.

Comment: But like how? I don't get it. Inside of the .then() block?